# SQL - include this record if these other records are included

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Over simplifying here, but I need help. Let's say I have a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Policy p
JOIN OtherPolicyFile o on o.PolicyId = p.PolicyId 
WHERE OtherPolicyFile.Status IN (9,10)
```

OK, so here is the story. I need to also pull any OtherPolicyFile where the Status = 11, but ONLY if there is a matching OtherPolicyFile  with a status 9 or 10 as well.

In other words, I would not normally pull an OtherPolicyFile with status 11, but if that policy also has an OtherPolicyFile with a status 9 or 10, then I need to also pull any OtherPolicyFiles with a status of 11.

There is probably a really easy way to write this, but I'm frazzled at the moment and it is not coming to me without jumping through hoops. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So basically, you're trying to get status 11 if 9 and 10 also exist?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu I think he needs 11 if 9 OR 10 exist, right Todd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform one extra left join and test the left joined table for NULL:

```
SELECT p.*, o.* 
FROM Policy p
    JOIN OtherPolicyFile o on o.PolicyId = p.PolicyId 
    LEFT JOIN OtherPolicyFile o9or10 
        on o9or10.PolicyId = p.PolicyId and o9or10.Status IN (9,10)
WHERE o.Status IN (9,10)
    OR o.Status = 11 AND o9or10.PolicyId is NOT NULL
GROUP BY <whatever key you need>
```

But beware - you need to use GROUP BY so that the added LEFT JOIN doesn't duplicate lines. I cannot propose proper key because I don't know your schema, so fill in appropriate one (possibly the primary ID of OtherPolicyFile? So something like o.ID in your case? But I really don't know)

Comment: Thanks. I knew there had to be some kind of fairly simple approach, and I couldn't think of it. My mind kept going to reading everything into a temp table and then re-SELECTing through that, which seemed inefficient and over-kill. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: You are wellcome @Todd. Yes, most of the times you get by with simple JOINs. Just to combine them skillfully

Comment: @Tomas check my answer. Done without joins and really alot better

Answer (score 2):

I would add a subquery to see if 9 or 10 exists. Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a68c/2

```
SELECT * FROM Policy p
JOIN OtherPolicyFile o on o.PolicyId = p.PolicyId 
WHERE o.Status IN (9,10)
OR (o.Status = 11 AND
    exists (select * from OtherPolicyFile innerO 
              where innerO.PolicyId = p.PolicyId 
              and (innerO.Status = 9 or innerO.Status=10)))
```

Comment: This was a great answer, and pretty solid. Thank you. The only reason I selected the other reply was because it seems more efficient, and when added to my "real" code, less complicated.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this will give the best possible performance. Note no joins.

it will only execute on sql server 2005+

Be aware that you can't 'select *' and have identical column names in both tables for this to work. So you have to specify which columns you need.

```
SELECT * from 
(
  SELECT  <your columns>, 
  statuscheck = min(nullif(o.status, 11)) over (partition by o.PolicyId)
  FROM Policy p
  JOIN OtherPolicyFile o on o.PolicyId = p.PolicyId 
  WHERE o.Status IN (9,10,11)
) a
WHERE statuscheck is not null
```

Comment: BTW, subqueries are much more inefficient than joins, because they mostly result in temporary table.

Comment: @Tomas I have no ADDITIONAL joins and this subquery is way more effective than your left join. It basically selects all rows with 9,10,11 and rejects those "partitions" without 9 and 10

Comment: Interesting, though this is not standard SQL, this is some extension I don't know. However I am not very sure this is more efficient than a left join; you use subquery and also `min over partition by`..

Comment: Which column are you partitioning by?

Comment: @jtseng well spotted. I partitioned on an imaginary column. It has been corrected.

Comment: This is creative Tom. I have to admit the Min Over Partition is beyond my own SQL knowledge. I went with the answer above because I needed an "now" that I could implement, but what I'd like to do, once the rush to get my code out this weekend is over I'd like to run the three approaches presented here and get some efficiency ratings to compare.

Comment: @Tomas by testing jseng's script vs mine, my script took 7 seconds, jseng's script took 59 seconds. jsengs script is faster than yours.

Comment: jsengs script is faster than mine? Really? Strange. How much?